# Remove white space using a Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to write a shell script. It will take in a .txt file and output a .csv file.

The .txt file is a two dimensional array of text. But there is an unknown number of spaces between each entry.

So for example, the inputted file might look like:

```
Name    Subject   Grade
Fred English      A
James   French  B
Mark      Maths      D
```

And I want it to look like

```
Name,Subject,Grade
Fred,English,A
James,French,B
Mark,Maths,D
```

In pseudocode it would be:

1. search for the string containing two spaces and replace with a single space
2. repeat 1. until no more changes are being made (or just 10 times, say)
3. replace " " with ","

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one step:

```
sed 's/  */,/g'
```

Comment: Why not ` +` instead of `  *`?

Comment: @MrTux It just doesn't work: `+` is part of so called "extended" regular expression. Would require to write `sed -r 's/ +/,/'` to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not shell, but a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pi -e 's| +|,|g' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tr -s ' ' , < input-file.txt
```